# Empty all the fields of a structure array in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

For simplicity's sake let us stick to [this official Matlab example](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-a-structure-array.html).

I run the following code, and a structure with three fields is created.

```
patient.name = 'John Doe';
patient.billing = 127.00;
patient.test = [79, 75, 73; 180, 178, 177.5; 220, 210, 205];
```

Then, in order to create a structure array, I simply have to do the following.

```
patient(2).name = 'Ann Lane';
patient(2).billing = 28.50;
patient(2).test = [68, 70, 68; 118, 118, 119; 172, 170, 169];
```

At this point I have a structure array that is clearly represented by [this picture](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/examples/strucdem_img02.png):
[image]

Here comes the question: how can I empty all the fields of the structure `patient(2)`?

Ideally (forgive the abuse of notation) I would like to do something like `patient(2).* = {}`.

Calling the fields one by one is not an option because in my actual code I have a lot of fields, neither I can convert the structure to a cell.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Ander Biguri Thank you so much for adding the image to the question, I did not have the necessary reputation at the time I posted :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this operation is frequent, a good idea would be to prepare an `EMPTY_PATIENT`:

```
EMPTY_PATIENT = struct( ...
   'name', {},          ...
   'billing', {},       ...
   'test', {}           ...
);
```

then use the simple assignment (which is very fast) to empty the position:

```
patient(2) = EMPTY_PATIENT;
```

Comment: For sure this is the safest and fastest way to go, using a foo empty structure! Thank you CST :)

Comment: As a general remark: if there is only one level and you have a lot of fields to populate, you can get away with entering one fieldname and MATLAB will populate the remainder. For example: `patient(end+1).name = []; empty_patient = patient(end); patient(end) = [];` Saves some typing

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there's a clever way to do it without the loop but this works fine.

```
fieldstoclear = fieldnames(patient(2));

for ii = 1:length(fieldstoclear)
    patient(2).(fieldstoclear{ii}) = [];
end
```

edit: forgot about `structfun`:

```
patient(2) = structfun(@(x) [], patient(2), 'UniformOutput',false)
```

**Note**: Neither method will preserve nested structures.

Comment: Thank you excaza, this goes in the right direction. Anyway the nested structures are of importance in this case, so I cannot really accept this as an answer! But again it really is a step forward, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
 patient(2) = [];
```

Might be what you are looking for. This will eliminate that element from the structure.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I actually need to keep the element because the size of the array plays a role in my code. I expressly need to empty its field, not to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a generic solution for any number of fields.

```
fields=fieldnames(patient);
patient(2)=cell2struct(cell(length(fields), 1), fields);
```